# How to get path of tag in xml while using NSXmlParser in iphone?

Tags: ios, xml

I am new to iphone development. In my application, there are multiple tags are of the same name. I want to get the path of the tags so that i make it sure that i get the right tag.
My xml structure is like

```
<items>
   <name></name>
   <link></link>
   <items>
          <name></name>
          <link></link>
   </items>
</items>
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed exactly the same thing, guess this is an old question but I will write down what I have implemented:

```
- (void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"parserDidStartDocument");
    self.errorParsingDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    self.nodeStack = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    NSLog(@"didStartElement --> %@", elementName);
    [self.nodeStack addObject:elementName]; // Push
    NSString *currentPath = [self pathFromNodeStack];
//    [self.errorParsingDictionary setObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
//                                    forKey:currentPath];
    [self.errorParsingDictionary setValue:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
                               forKeyPath:currentPath];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"foundCharacters --> %@", string);
    NSString *currentPath = [self pathFromNodeStack];
//    NSMutableString *mutableString = [self.errorParsingDictionary objectForKey:currentPath];
    id nodeValue = [self.errorParsingDictionary valueForKeyPath:currentPath];
    NSMutableString *nodeString = nil;
    if (nil==nodeValue || ![nodeValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
    {
        nodeString = [NSMutableString string];
//        [self.errorParsingDictionary setObject:mutableString
//                                        forKey:currentPath];
        [self.errorParsingDictionary setValue:nodeString
                                   forKeyPath:currentPath];
    }
    [nodeString appendString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    NSLog(@"didEndElement   --> %@", elementName);
    [self.nodeStack removeObjectAtIndex:[self.nodeStack count]-1]; // Pop
}

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
    NSLog(@"parserDidEndDocument");
    self.nodeStack = nil;
}

-(NSString*)pathFromNodeStack
{
    NSMutableString *path = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int i=0; i<self.nodeStack.count; i++)
    {
        [path appendString:[self.nodeStack objectAtIndex:i]];
        if (i!=self.nodeStack.count-1)
        {
            // If it is not the last object
            [path appendString:@"."];
        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

After the completion of parsing, you can now use the dictionary: `self.errorParsingDictionary` to get the values of any path, like this:

```
NSString *nodeValue = [self.errorParsingDictionary valueForKeyPath: @"items.items.name"];
```

Hope this helps.